# Google recaptcha hides after changing component via react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, recaptcha

I have this issue where when i switch from one component to other using react router my google recaptcha div stops displaying.
My component with google recaptcha

```
   class Contact extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    document.title = "Contact";
  }
  errorHandle(err){
    let loc = document.getElementById("err-" + err);
    loc.className = "error-live";
    setTimeout(() =>{
      loc.className = "error";
    },errSpeed);
  }
  sendMail(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let message = document.getElementById("message").value,
        name = document.getElementById("name").value,
        email = document.getElementById("email").value,
        captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if(email.length < 4 || email.length < 4 || name.length < 4){
      this.errorHandle("short");
      return;
    }else if(email.indexOf("@") === -1){
      this.errorHandle("email");//make error
      return;
    }else if(captcha.length === 0){
      this.errorHandle("recaptcha");//make error
      return;
    }
    sa
      .post("./back-end/contact.php")
      .send({name,email,message,captcha})
      .type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      .end(function(err,res){
        res = res.text;
        if(res.search("sent") > 0){
          dbId("contact-done").style.display = "block";
          dbId("contact").style.opacity = 0;
          dbId("contact-done").style.opacity = 1;
          setTimeout(() =>{
            window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace("contact",""));
          },errSpeed);
        }else if(res === "failToSend")
          alert("Failed to send the message please try again");
      })

  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className = "contact">
        <div id = "contact-done"><p>Thank you for contacting us</p></div>
        <form id = "contact" className="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact me</legend>

            <label>Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></input>

            <label>Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"></input>

            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea id = "message"></textarea>

            <div id = "recaptcha-contact" className="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="myKeyHere"></div>

            <div id = "err-email" className = "error">Invalid Email adress</div>
            <div id = "err-recaptcha" className = "error">Please fill in google recaptcha</div>
            <div id = "err-short" className = "error">Each field has to be atleast 4 characters long</div>

            <button onClick = {this.sendMail.bind(this)} className="pure-button pure-button-primary">Send</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I load the `http://localhost/contact` it shows up,however as soonas I change path to lets say `http://localhost/articles` and switch back it disappears.What could be the cause?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a while and could not find the solution to the problem,what I ended up doing is re rendering the recaptcha each time component is visited :

```
componentDidMount(){
  setTimeout(() =>{
    window.grecaptcha.render('recaptcha-contact', {
       sitekey: "key",
       callback: function(resp){}
    });
  },300);
}
```

Timeout is there since grecaptcha would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

reference to this link https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3256

You should load the google captcha js file every time the component get loaded.

it can simply done by using loadJs module.

Install the module with `npm install loadjs` and you just need to add
`var loadjs = require('loadjs');`
`loadjs('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fa');` to your component.

Also you don`t even need to add the js file to your html codes!